# Default install path to ProgramFilesFolder without specifying ProgramFilesFolder in wxs

Tags: c#, wix

I currently have a legacy Visual Studio Install Projects project that creates an MSI. With this I can specify "TARGETDIR="somepath"" on the command line and have it install to "somepath". Now with WIX, if I don't specify ProgramFilesFolder in my wxs, "TARGETDIR" still works, however in my UI of the installer the default path is "C:\Manufacturer\Product" whereas I still want it to default to ProgramFilesFolder. Having support of "TARGETDIR" is necessary to also support upgrading to the legacy MSI from within the app itself.

I have found some ways to change the UI default directory to ProgramFilesFolder, however TARGETDIR doesn't change to this directory (or a directory the user specifies) so it still installs to C:\Manufacturer\Product.

Does anyone have any ideas here? I'm guessing some kind of custom action will do it but I feel like I've tried most of the suggestions such as:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13058798/9993088 but this would override any selected directory in the or at the command line
- I've also tried creating a WiX property "TARGETDIR" to expose it on the command line but as this is already an internal one it didn't make a difference.
- [How to set default value of WiX Msi install path in the ui to Program Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731235/how-to-set-default-value-of-wix-msi-install-path-in-the-ui-to-program-files) as mentioned this would then prevent me from using "TARGETDIR" on the command line
- https://wixtoolset.org//documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_advanced.html and then using a custom action to set "TARGETDIR" to "APPLICATIONFOLDER". With this I can set the default location to ProgramFilesFolder but then I haven't found a way to set "TARGETDIR" at the right time to use the command line value or the user selected one. I almost need a way to do "if 'APPLICATIONFOLDER' is not default; use its value OR if 'TARGETDIR' is not default; use its value ELSE use the default value". This also seems to not allow variable expansion so I can't use "[ProgramFilesFolder]", I have to explicitly write out "C:\Program Files..." which isn't ideal.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="blah">
```

As mentioned, I must be able to use "TARGETDIR" and not "INSTALLDIR" (although that works).

If I really *have* to use "INSTALLDIR" then I can make it work but it makes maintaining the legacy MSI and the WiX one tricky due to the nature of how they're used.

*Edit*

Solution:
`<Custom Action="SetINSTALLDIR" Before="AppSearch">Not Installed</Custom>` in both `InstallExecuteSequence` and `InstallUISequence`.

This points to:
`<CustomAction Id="SetINSTALLDIR" BinaryKey="CustomActionsBinary" DllEntry="SetInstallDir" />`

`SetInstallDir` is the following:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult SetInstallDir(Session session)
{
    TraceLogger.yRTraceInfo(nameof(SetInstallDir));
    string installDir = session["APPLICATIONFOLDER"];
    string targetDir = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        targetDir = session["TARGETDIR"];
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.log(e.Message);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(installDir) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetDir))
    {
        session["APPLICATIONFOLDER"] = targetDir;
        console.log($"Setting APPLICATIONFOLDER to {targetDir}");
    }
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could have a SetProperty custom action to assign INSTALLDIR a value if it is empty and TARGETDIR has a value and  Not Installed.  Schedule it early on in both the Install UI and Install Execute sequences ahead of AppSearch.

FYI in WiX INSTALLLOCATION is more commonly used. INSTALLDIR is more of an InstallShield thing and TARGETDIR a Visual Studio thing.

```
<SetProperty Id="INSTALLDIR" Value="[TARGETDIR]" Before="AppSearch">Not INSTALLDIR and TARGETDIRDIR and Not Installed</SetProperty>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have done the trick. Updated my question with the implementation details.

Comment: I didn't mean for you to write a custom action but to simply use SetProperty. Answer updated with an untested example.  FWIW the custom action approach can be useful when you want to have additional business logic like check the directory is a fixed local disk but otherwise it just adds complexity and possible failure points to the install.